# Hive's performance tuning

Tags: performance, hive

I am working on a project where in I have to tune hive's performance. I have found nine most important parameters that will help in tuning hive's performance. They are as follows(in no specific order):

1. hive.exec.reducers.max
2. hive.limit.optimize.fetch.max
3. hive.limit.row.max.size
4. hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions
5. hive.index.compact.query.max.entries
6. hive.merge.size.per.task
7. hive.index.compact.query.max.size
8. hive.metastore.server.min.threads
9. hive.mapjoin.check.memory.rows

I wanted to know whether I am going in the right direction or not? Please let me know if I missed out on some other parameters also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from the parameters listed above, the link provides some wonderful insights related to Hive Performance tuning in general:
https://hortonworks.com/blog/5-ways-make-hive-queries-run-faster/

Answer (score 0):

Consider running hive on tez engine which is significantly runs faster than MapReduce.

hive.execution.engine = tez